# Why is the path to a shader in my application nil?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, opengl-es, glsl

When I try to load a GLSL shader from my iPhone application bundle, the path to it is being reported as nil.  This shader is in my Xcode project.

Pictures are be best way to describe this:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does pathForResource also return nil for other files? Just curious: Have you made sure that [NSBundle mainBundle] doesn't return nil? (I mean it shouldn't but....)

Comment: I'm checking that now, thanks... Oddly it seems some other files haven't been transferred to the app package but the shader ones have.

Comment: No, the other files seem fine. The mainBundle method returns an NSBundle object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A potential solution to this problem is to go to "Targets" and then make sure the files are in "Copy Bundle Resources". That fixed it for me.

Just a ton of shader related issues to get through now.

Comment: Yes, by default Xcode treats all shaders as source code files, rather than resources.  You always have to remember to move them to the correct build phase.

Comment: When you create a project and manually add files :  Shader.vsh and Shader.fsh they will appear in "Build Phases" section : "Compile Sources".  You then need to drag N drop both files out of "Compile Sources" and into "Copy Bundle Resources" - worked for me

Answer (score 3):

Might not be copied to your bundle at build time...  Right click on "Shader.vsh" and select "Get Info" - the the "Targets" tab.  Make sure the checkbox for the target you are calling is checked.

Comment: Thank you both for answers. The target is selected, definitely.

Comment: I checked the built app file and the shaders are in the contents.

Comment: Select "Get Info" from where?

Answer (score 1):

did you set the file to copy to the application bundle? it may not be copied. Check the preference, I do not remember, select the file and hit "CTRL-i"